# How to manage a datasnap connection for multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, connection, datasnap

I have come to the conclusion that only 1 client thread can access the server through a connection. But how to manage this?

Do I need to lock the connection every time I use the TSQLConnection. With a Server Method for instance?

How to automate my Server Methods to Lock and Unlock the Connection to my server?

Should i convert all my server method calls From

```
ServerMethod();
```

to

```
Try
  Datamodule.lock;
  ServerMethod
Finally
  Datamodule.unlock;
end;
```

Or Should I give my Threads New Connections?

I use other threads for printing, this needs information from the server.
Printing should be done in the background but stil uses the SQL connection from the main Application.

**Edit**: The problem with creating a new connection is that the server creates a new ClientSession. So i need to Create and close this Session. Is there a way to create a new connection to the same session?

Comment: Why don't you use a separate SQLConnection for each thread?

Comment: @UweRaabe. Cloning the conenction works, but the server still sees this as a new connection := new license on my database, wich is something we don't want right?

Comment: I guess there is not much you can do about it.